# Assigning GraphQL result to a nested State in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to append the result of a query to a GraphQL to a state in my function, but I can't make it work. The code is:

```
 export default function DisplayCharts() {
        const [ state, setState ] = useState({
          dataRows: [],
          currentPage: 0,
        });
    
      const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(
        getAllRank,
        {
          fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network"
        }
      );
       setState({
         dataRows: {
          ...state,
          dataRows: [1]
         },
       }); //This works, but it doesn't when it is inside of useEffect
      useEffect(() => {
        if(loading === false && data){
           console.log(data.getAllRank.rows);//This returns the data
           setState({
              dataRows: {
                ...state,
               dataRows: [1]
             },
           }); //Here the setState doesn't work.
         }
      }, [loading, data, currentPage]);
    
      if (loading) return "Loading...";
      if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;
      console.log(state.dataRows); //Returns empty

  }
```

I tried iterating through the items and add them one by one, but also doesn't work. Any suggestion on how to add the collection that I receive from the GraphQL query to this function State?

Thanks!

Comment: how did you determine that it doesn't work? This version looks correct to me: `setState(prevState => {return {...prevState, dataRows: data.getAllRank.rows}})`

Comment: Hi @kkesley, I run console.log(state) and the array (dataRows) is empty.

Comment: where did you run it? can you show us the full component?

Comment: Hey @kkesley, thanks for taking the time. I just added the console.log to the code, that's the entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log(state.dataRows)` is empty because React will update your state in the **next render**.

Try this:

```
export default function DisplayCharts() {
        const [ state, setState ] = useState({
          dataRows: [],
          currentPage: 0,
        });
    
      const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(
        getAllRank,
        {
          fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network"
        }
      );
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if(loading === false && data){
           console.log(data.getAllRank.rows);//This returns the data
           setState(prevState => {return {...prevState, dataRows: data.getAllRank.rows}});
           
         }
      }, [loading, data, currentPage]);
      console.log(state.dataRows); //<----- this is the only thing I moved
    
      if (loading) return "Loading...";
      if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;
  }
```

I moved the `console.log` statement outside of the `useEffect`. This will run multiple times as it will be executed every render.

Comment: console.log outside of useEffect also returns empty. I just updated the code, the problem seems to be with the usage of setState inside of useEffect.

Comment: yes. the updated version has the incorrect usage of `setState`. Try this one `setState(prevState => {return {...prevState, dataRows: data.getAllRank.rows}});`